# TEAMS bot. "TypeError: source.on is not a function" in 'createConversation' method

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a TEAMS node.js bot running locally (with ngrok). I receive messages from TEAMS client and echo works

```
context.sendActivity(`You said '${context.activity.text}'`);
```

I need to send a proactive message, but i get an error creating conversation pbject.

My code:

```
...
await BotConnector.MicrosoftAppCredentials.trustServiceUrl(sServiceUrl);

var credentials = new BotConnector.MicrosoftAppCredentials({
    appId: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    appPassword: "YYYYYYYYYYYYY"
});

var connectorClient = new BotConnector.ConnectorClient(credentials, { baseUri: sServiceUrl });

const parameters = {
    members: [{ id: sUserId }],
    isGroup: false,
    channelData:
    {
        tenant: {
            id: sTenantId
        }
    }
};

// Here I get the error: "TypeError: source.on is not a function"
var conversationResource = await connectorClient.conversations.createConversation(parameters);

await connectorClient.conversations.sendToConversation(conversationResource.id, {
   type: "message",
   from: { id: credentials.appId },
   recipient: { id: sUserId },
   text: 'This a message from Bot Connector Client (NodeJS)'
});
```

String values are correct and I have a valid connectorClient.

Thanks in advance,

Diego

Comment: I see that I get he same error in other methods, like updateActivity...

Comment: Hi Steven, I see your message now. Today I will try it and tell you. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. I must set credentials/conector/trust in the correct order:

```
credentials = new MicrosoftAppCredentials(process.env.MicrosoftAppId, process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword);

connectorClient = new ConnectorClient(credentials, { baseUri: activity.serviceUrl });

MicrosoftAppCredentials.trustServiceUrl(activity.serviceUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are close but just need to make a couple modifications. It's hard to tell because I can't see all of your code.

Here, I add the Teams middleware to the adapter in `index.js` and am making the call that triggers the proactive message from within a waterfall step in `mainDialog.js`. The location of the code shouldn't matter as long as you can pass `context` in.

Also, with regards to your message construction, sending the text alone is sufficient. The recipient is already specified in the paremeters with the rest of the activity properties assigned via the connector. There is no need to reconstruct the activity (unless you really need to).

Lastly, be sure to trust the `serviceUrl`. I do this via the `onTurn` method in `mainBot.js`.

Hope of help!

**index.js**

```js
const teams = require('botbuilder-teams');

const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
  appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
  appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword
})
  .use(new teams.TeamsMiddleware())
```

**mainDialog.js**

```js
const { ConnectorClient, MicrosoftAppCredentials } = require('botframework-connector');

async teamsProactiveMessage ( stepContext ) {
  const credentials = new MicrosoftAppCredentials(process.env.MicrosoftAppId, process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword);
  const connector = new ConnectorClient(credentials, { baseUri: stepContext.context.activity.serviceUrl });
  const roster = await connector.conversations.getConversationMembers(stepContext.context.activity.conversation.id);

  const parameters = {
    members: [
      {
        id: roster[0].id
      }
    ],
    channelData: {
      tenant: {
        id: roster[0].tenantId
      }
    }
  };

  const conversationResource = await connector.conversations.createConversation(parameters);
  const message = MessageFactory.text('This is a proactive message');
  await connector.conversations.sendToConversation(conversationResource.id, message);

  return stepContext.next();
}
```

**mainBot.js**

```js
this.onTurn(async (context, next) => {
  if (context.activity.channelId === 'msteams') {
    MicrosoftAppCredentials.trustServiceUrl(context.activity.serviceUrl);
  }
  await next();
});
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Steven, I saw your message on monday but I added a comment to my question, not to your reply. Maybe you did not see it. First, thanks a lot. Besides, I added a new reply to add more info. I would really appreciate any jelp, I am a bit desperated with this error...

Answer (score 0):

I created my bot with Yeoman, so I had a running example which can respond to an incoming message.
https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/bot-service/javascript/bot-builder-javascript-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

With that, I can respond to an incoming message and it works

My complete code:

index.js: // Created automatically, not modified

```
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT License.

const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const path = require('path');
const restify = require('restify');

// Import required bot services.
// See https://aka.ms/bot-services to learn more about the different parts of a bot.
const { BotFrameworkAdapter } = require('botbuilder');

// This bot's main dialog.
const { MyBot } = require('./bot');

// Import required bot configuration.
const ENV_FILE = path.join(__dirname, '.env');
dotenv.config({ path: ENV_FILE });

// Create HTTP server
const server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, () => {
    console.log(`\n${ server.name } listening to ${ server.url }`);
    console.log(`\nGet Bot Framework Emulator: https://aka.ms/botframework-emulator`);
    console.log(`\nTo test your bot, see: https://aka.ms/debug-with-emulator`);
});

// Create adapter.
// See https://aka.ms/about-bot-adapter to learn more about how bots work.
const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
    appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
    appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword
});

// Catch-all for errors.
adapter.onTurnError = async (context, error) => {
    // This check writes out errors to console log .vs. app insights.
    console.error(`\n [onTurnError]: ${ error }`);
    // Send a message to the user
    await context.sendActivity(`Oops. Something went wrong!`);
};

// Create the main dialog.
const myBot = new MyBot();

// Listen for incoming requests.
server.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
    adapter.processActivity(req, res, async (context) => {
        // Route to main dialog.
        await myBot.run(context);
    });
});
```

My bot file. bot.js // created automatically, modified to add proactive messages

```
   const { ConnectorClient, MicrosoftAppCredentials, BotConnector } = require('botframework-connector');
   const { ActivityHandler } = require('botbuilder');

   class MyBot extends ActivityHandler {

    constructor() {
        super();
        // See https://aka.ms/about-bot-activity-message to learn more about the message and other activity types.
        this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {
            //await context.sendActivity(`You said '${context.activity.text}'`); // It works
            var activity = context.activity;
            await MicrosoftAppCredentials.trustServiceUrl(activity.serviceUrl);
            var connectorClient = new ConnectorClient(credentials, { baseUri: activity.serviceUrl });
            const parameters = {
                members: [{ id: activity.from.id }],
                isGroup: false,
                channelData:
                {
                    tenant: {
                        id: activity.conversation.tenantId
                    }
                }
            };
        var conversationResource = await connectorClient.conversations.createConversation(parameters);  

    });
}

module.exports.MyBot = MyBot;
```

In 'createConversation' is where I get the error:

```
 [onTurnError]: TypeError: source.on is not a function
```

This code will be in a method, to call it when required, I put it in 'onMessage' just to simplify

I think my code is like yours... But I'm afraid I am missing something or doing sth wrong...

Thanks for your help,

Diego

Answer (score 0):

I have a stack trace of the error, and it seems to be related to 'delayed stream' node module. I add as a response since it is too long for a comment:

```
(node:28248) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: source.on is not a function
        at Function.DelayedStream.create ([Bot Project Path]\node_modules\delayed-stream\lib\delayed_stream.js:33:10)
        at FormData.CombinedStream.append ([Bot Project Path]\node_modules\combined-stream\lib\combined_stream.js:45:37)
        at FormData.append ([Bot Project Path]\node_modules\form-data\lib\form_data.js:74:3)
        at MicrosoftAppCredentials.refreshToken ([Bot Project Path]\node_modules\botframework-connector\lib\auth\microsoftAppCredentials.js:127:20)
        at MicrosoftAppCredentials.getToken ([Bot Project Path]\node_modules\botframework-connector\lib\auth\microsoftAppCredentials.js:91:32)
        at MicrosoftAppCredentials.signRequest ([Bot Project Path]\node_modules\botframework-connector\lib\auth\microsoftAppCredentials.js:71:38)
        at SigningPolicy.signRequest ([Bot Project Path]\node_modules\@azure\ms-rest-js\dist\msRest.node.js:2980:44)
        at SigningPolicy.sendRequest ([Bot Project Path]\node_modules\@azure\ms-rest-js\dist\msRest.node.js:2984:21)
        at ConnectorClient.ServiceClient.sendRequest ([Bot Project Path]\node_modules\@azure\ms-rest-js\dist\msRest.node.js:3230:29)
        at ConnectorClient.ServiceClient.sendOperationRequest ([Bot Project Path]\node_modules\@azure\ms-rest-js\dist\msRest.node.js:3352:27)
```